# Equivariant Cohomology of flag varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, flag-varieties

Let $G$ be a simple simply connected algebraic group and $T$ be a maximal torus in $G$. Let $B$ be a Borel containing $T$ and $N(T)/T$ be the Weyl group. We have nice actions of $T$ and $W$ on the Flag variety $G/B$. For the torus action the $T$-equivariant cohomology and the structure of the cohomology modules have been studied explicitly. Has any one studied the same for the Weyl group action on $G/B$ ? Any reference or results in this direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: What's your action of W on the flag variety? I don't know of any natural ones (because I don't know of any natural embeddings of W into G.)

Comment: The natural action is of $W$ on the right of $G/T$, not $G/B$, but they're homotopic and so have the same cohomology. If that's what you want, then as a $W$-module it's the regular representation. This is proved in e.g. Humphreys' gray book on Coxeter groups, by a Galois theory argument.